# How would I access something like assists or killPoints in this JSON in Java?

Tags: java, json, api

I'm trying to use the PUBG API (popular PC game) and I am having trouble using JSON (first time). I just want to access figures that are further embedded within the JSON array.

I have tried accessing index numbers of the JSON array but it seemed to not work

Here is the JSON im trying to use

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKit4.jpg "json"

Here is what I've tried

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    StringBuffer response =  new StringBuffer();

    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://api.pubg.com/shards/steam/seasons/lifetime/gameMode/squad-fpp/players?filter[playerIds]=account.0165929b76b147d1a453bbfd21a58b4b");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + API_KEY);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/vnd.api+json");

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        response = new StringBuffer();


        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("============");
    System.out.println("============");
    JSONObject myResponse = new JSONObject(response.toString());


    JSONArray arr = myResponse.getJSONArray("data");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
    {
        String post_id = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("type");
        System.out.println("name: " + post_id);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why it seems not working, what you get instead?

Comment: I strongly recommend investigating any of the number of Java REST clients (I tend to use Spring RestTemplate); any decent one will reduce your entire network section to two lines (one to set the Authorization header, one to execute the request), and Jackson or Gson will parse the JSON into a Java object (and most REST libraries will automatically process it for you).